# Make 2 Divs side by side Html Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

My problem is that I can't place 2+ divs in a single line . I can't use float because I have an unstable number of divs (A div for every post in django )
This is the code I am using :

### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "Css/indexstyle.css" %}">
    <title>Temporary</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for post in posts %}
    <a href="#"><div class="cl1">
        <img src="{% static 'Img/img.jpg' %}" id="picture">
        <center>{{ post.title}}</center>
        </center>
    </div></a>
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

### indexstyle.css

```
.product {
    height: 350px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 2em;
    float: left;
}

img{
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

a{
    text-decoration : none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your expected visual outcome is?

Comment: If you just want to place 2 divs side by side instead of float:left, you can use display:inline-block

Comment: an unstable number of divs. WOW! and you want to put them side by side. 
i am not asking why, but you can do it with `display:table` for the parent div (**Must be out of your for loop**) display:`table-cell` for each div

Comment: inline-block worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `div` tag with classes `row` and `col` to get your divs side by side even if number of divs is unknown.